# mean curvature and volumes of submanifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

How to relate the mean curvature vector evolution over a submanifold of an euclidean space to growth of the volumes of geodesic balls. Can i determine the volume of a geodesic ball by integrating the norm of the mean curvature vector? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "growth of the volumes of geodesic balls."? Are
you talking about the time evolution of a family of submanifolds, or a fixed submanifold with an intrinsic geodesic ball of increasing radius?

Comment: Yes, the second option: a fixed submanifold of euclidean space. How would the evolution of the mean curvature affect the volumes of intrinsic geodesic balls if the radius is being increased.